# Reopen last closed tab in inPrivate mode on Microsoft Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge

Is there a way to reopen the recently closed tab(s) in inPrivate mode on Microsoft Edge browser? Is there a tweak for this somewhere in the settings?

Comment: I know, there are privacy reasons for disallowing that in inPrivate mode on Edge, but e.g. Firefox's private mode allows reopening last closed tabs.

Comment: It’s not allowed in Chrome, Chromium, Edge, or any browser based on Chromium.  Edge isn’t Firefox, you can’t easily compare it Edge to Firefox, they are different browsers

Comment: I know that all @Ramhound

Comment: have you found the solution?